# BigQuery Connector in Google Sheet limited to 10,000 rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'm running a simple query from Google Sheets, to a BigQuery table using the BigQuery connector on Google Sheets.

The query size--when executed on BigQuery is 3.5 MB. Nothing huge. 16,000 rows of data.

However, when running from Google Sheets, it says "Limited to 10,000 rows".

Now, I'm not able to find out where that limit comes from. We need our data to be accessible here at work and this constraint is causing trouble.

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you have a link to the specific connector you are using?

Comment: That’s the default one that’s on Google Sheets.

Comment: PS: the PowerBI connector is able to retrieve all rows from that table. So that seems to be some issue specific to Google Sheet Connector.

Comment: PS2: installed ODBC connector for Excel and I'm getting all rows from that table there as well.